# Check if the record has been inserted into the database table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I need to check if a record has been inserted into the table , if yes I have to retrieve specific information and search in the second table .Please tell me the proper way to search the second table as soon as a record arrives in the first table.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you please share your table structure

Comment: @Kenzo: I am using Mysql database.I have two tables Buy & Sell,now whenever record is inserted either in Buy or in Sell I have to retrieve the  fields "location" and then I have to search in another table for records where location match. what would be the best method for searching. Comparing a newly inserted records in either of the tables with all records in another table would cause an performance issue according to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, what exactly are you looking for. Are you looking for [**Triggers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) in your database, which will get fires as soon as record is inserted?

```
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
TRIGGER trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event
ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW trigger_body
```